# iOS Animate UIPicker height change

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have UITableView with static cells. I have set equal Content View height constraint equals to UIPicker view height. I have also implemented didSelectRowAt method with changing UITableViewCell content view.
[image]
https://youtu.be/lJuTLQ1oTaE

Magic happens, changing height of TableViewCell is animated. But the following change of UIPickerView height is happening simultaneously, with no animation. I have tried to put UIView.animate with layoutIfNeeded(), but it did not help.

How to animate such auto change of UIPickerView height?

```
// TableView functions
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        let reuseIdentifier = cell.reuseIdentifier
        guard reuseIdentifier != nil else {return}

    if reuseIdentifier == "currencyPickerTableViewCell" && self.selectedCellIndexPath == nil {
        self.skipCellsFromGestureRecognition.append(indexPath)
        self.selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath
        print(currencyPicker.constraints)
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    } else if reuseIdentifier == "currencyPickerTableViewCell" && self.selectedCellIndexPath != nil {
        self.selectedCellIndexPath = nil
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if self.selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
        return self.selectedCellHeight
    } else {
        return self.unselectedCellHeight
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The animation actually happens but as the font of the **UIPicker** stays the same you can't see it , so change the font inside **UIView.animate** , also note that your width of the picker is static so, number of trimmed characters will be increased as the font becomes larger . . .

Comment: You probably misunderstood my question. I do not change font and it's size. I'm trying to expand UIPickerView with row.